# Angular15: What is the official way to support older browsers?

Tags: javascript, angular

My angular build is not working on IOS12 it is showing just a blank page.

Here are my `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0"
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
.....
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"]
....
```

How can i make it compatible for at least IOS 12 because i have already another app which is using angular 13 and is working on IOS 12

Comment: And when you connect safari to the remote debugger what sort of errors do you see?

Comment: You should have a browserlistrc file in your root. Check that out maybe?

Comment: you need to check all your deprecated dependences and find some way maybe using polyfill like a workaround

Comment: https://caniuse.com/sr_es13

Comment: @MikeOne i do not have any .browserlistrc on my root app

Answer (score 0):

i think the reason maybe is not working on ios  12 that u are using ES2022 target in your tsconfig.json it can be not supported by older browsers and devices .
here's an example of the new tsconfig.json file :

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "ES2015",
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [
  "es2015",
  "dom"
],
"sourceMap": true,
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "@/*": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "@@/*": [
    "src/assets/*"
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: If i change the tsconfig.json as in your example my app is not compatible with the newer version of IOS

Comment: What if you use both ES2015 and ES2022?